# LSNRCTL cannot stop Listener

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, listener

When I'm trying to lsnrctl start, i have following error:

`TNS-01106: Listener using listener name LISTENER has already been started`

However, if i try to lsnrctl stop:

`Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521)) TNS-01189: The listener could not authenticate the user`

As we can see, HOST is empty. How can I solve this porblem?

Comment: Do it with the user that has the necessary privileges.

Comment: @BalazsPapp what do u mean? Oracle user do not have privileges?)

Comment: Exactly. If Grid Infrastructure was installed as e.g `grid` user and the database software was installed as e.g `oracle` user, `oracle` user can not stop the listener that runs as `grid` user.

Comment: @BalazsPapp thanks a lot, it worked (with 'grid' user)! 
Oracle, not thanks for not clear error empty host  ᕦ(ò_óˇ)ᕤ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @BalazsPapp mentioned in his comment, the problem was in ssh user.
It worked as expected when a switched to 'grid' user.